# How to get range of substring in swift3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How to get range of substring in swift3?

```
 let string  = "Please Click Here"
```

I need range of click

Comment: That question has at least 3 answers which show how to use `range(of:)` to find the range of a substring.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
let string = "Please Click Here"
if let range = string.range(of: "Click") {
   print(range)

}
```

Answer (score 16):

Convert to `NSString` and user `rangeOf`:

```
let string  = "Please Click Here"
let range = (string as NSString).range(of: "Click", options: .caseInsensitive)
print(range)
```

Comment: how to get case sensitive comparison result?